# How to put route aliases in the individual service settings instead of the API gateway service in Molecular

Tags: node.js, microservices, moleculer

As mentioned in the documentation route aliases can be put in the **API** service, but I want to put the aliases in the individual service settings, how can I do that?

Let's say I have a **users** service and **API gateway**,

and the users service have a role action and it will just send back the id *as an example*

If I send a get request to `/users/role/1` I will get `1` as result

### It works like this

*api.service.js*

```js
"use strict";

const ApiGateway = require("moleculer-web");


module.exports = {
    name: "api",
    mixins: [ApiGateway],

    settings: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
        routes: [{
            path: "/api",
            whitelist: [
                // Access to any actions in all services under "/api" URL
                "**"
            ],
            aliases: {
                "GET users/role/:uid": "users.role"
            }
        }],

        // Serve assets from "public" folder
        assets: {
            folder: "public"
        },
    },
};
```

*users.service.js*

```js
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    name: "users",

    /**
     * Service settings
     */
    settings: {},

    /**
     * Actions
     */
    actions: {
        role: {
            cache: {
                keys: ["uid"]
            },
            rest: "GET role/:uid",
            handler(ctx) {
                return ctx.params.uid
            }
        }
    },
};
```

### wanted somthing like this

*api.service.js*

```js
"use strict";

const ApiGateway = require("moleculer-web");


module.exports = {
    name: "api",
    mixins: [ApiGateway],

    settings: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
        routes: [{
            path: "/api",
            whitelist: [
                // Access to any actions in all services under "/api" URL
                "**"
            ]
        }],

        // Serve assets from "public" folder
        assets: {
            folder: "public"
        },
    },
};
```

*users.service.js*

```js
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    name: "users",

    /**
     * Service settings
     */
    settings: {
        routes: [{
            path: "/",
            aliases: {
                "GET role/:uid": "role"
            }
        }],

    },

    /**
     * Actions
     */
    actions: {
        role: {
            cache: {
                keys: ["uid"]
            },
            rest: "GET role/:uid",
            handler(ctx) {
                return ctx.params.uid
            }
        }
    },
};
```

the goal is that every service is separated in its own project and the aliases for any service can be put in it and not in the API service

Answer (score 1):

```
// api.service.js
module.exports = {
    mixins: [ApiGateway],
    settings: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
        routes: [
            {
                path: "/",    
                whitelist: [
                    "users.**"
                ],   
                autoAliases: true
            }
        ]
    }
};

// users.service.js
module.exports = {
    name: "users",

    settings: {
        // Base path
        rest: "users/"
    },

    actions: {
        role: {
            cache: {
                keys: ["uid"]
            },
            rest: "GET role/:uid",
            handler(ctx) {
                return ctx.params.uid
            }
        }
    }
};
```